# Django: model for unusual table relationship in a legacy DB

Tags: python, django, model, legacy-database

I'm doing my first Django project and am wrestling with a legacy DB from a 3rd party program. The DB has a slightly unusual table structure for one section I'm trying to get to grips with.

The basic table layout is as follows:

```
PERSON
------
z_pk int primary key,
z_name text 

SPOUSEREL
---------
z_person int foreign_key(person.z_pk)
z_spouserel int
```

so for example, PERSON contains:

```
1, John Smith
2, Maggie Brown
3, Bob Johnson
4, Sarah Lee
```

And SPOUSEREL would contain the following:

```
1, 50
2, 50
1, 55
4, 55
```

This indicates that John Smith married Maggie Brown in "marriage number 50" and that John Smith also married Sarah Lee in "marriage number 55". The numbers 50 and 55 are numbers that simply create a link from one person to another to indicate a marriage and have no another relevance.

I've tried a combination of various `ManyToManyField` and `ForeignKey`, e.g.:

```
class Spouserel(models.Model):
    z_persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, db_column='z_pk')
    z_spouserels = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

but without success. From looking at the queries it's trying to execute, the lookup is failign with Django requiring an ID field but one is not present. I thought about using 'through' but in this case it would have to go through itself?

I'm not sure where to go on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your models should be like these

```
class Person(models.Model):
    z_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    z_name = models.TextField()

class Spouserel(models.Model):
    z_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='z_pk', primary_key=True)
    z_spouserel = models.IntegerField()
```

**Note**

The Spouserel model is more like a hack than a fix. Currently, the way Django works is that you would need to specify one of your model fields as a primary key. If it's unable to find such field, it will automatically add an `id` Autofield. To make your model work, you need to specify any field to be the primary key. It does not matter what field, Django just need to find `primary_key=True`. For more info, you can read this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/c1HZrJtsuPA).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rod. Unfortunately I can't make z_person a primary key due to the duplicated id's from the person table. Removing the primary_key parameter gets me back to the same problem of an id field missing
e.g.
`p = Zperson.objects.get(z_pk=41)`

Comment: As said in the link above, you can just choose any field and set `primary_key=True`. The field does not have to be unique. You just need to let Django know that you are setting that as the primary key so it won't add the id column.

Comment: As sorry I missed that. My old relational DB orimary key bias coming out. :)  That's done the trick. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. But, keep in mind that the approach above is more like a hack and some Django features may not work.